# IE e.target.id is not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
document.click = check;

function check(e)
{ 
    var obj = document.getElementById('calendar_widget');

    if (obj != 'null')
    {
        if (e.target.id != 'show_calender')
            obj.style.display='none';
    }
}
```

Error is in Internet Explorer: e.target.id is undefined.

Comment: Is it really so hard to check your post before posting? This time I fixed the code for you, at least a little bit. You want others to take the time to look at your code, so take the time to make it readable. There's still some formatting to do for you.

Comment: i dont knw how to insert codes.. where do i get this informations

Comment: When you put code in, select it and press the button with "101 010" on it

Comment: @midhun: click the help button above and to the right of where you type in your question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: This will add a newline before the code, and 4 spaces at the start of each line

Comment: Don't you mean "onclick", not "click"?

Comment: can u share ur html pls for better understanding of structure of two div "show_calender" and "calendar_widget".

Answer (score 40, accepted):

IE doesn't support the target property, they use srcElement instead.

Change:

```
if (e.target.id != 'show_calender')
```

to:

```
if ((e.target || e.srcElement).id != 'show_calender')
```

You may also need to add this to the beginning of your function:

```
if (!e) e = window.event
```

Your final code would look like this:

```
function check(e) { 
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var obj = document.getElementById('calendar_widget');

    if (obj != 'null') {
        if ((e.target || e.srcElement).id != 'show_calender')
                obj.style.display='none';
    }
}
```

Comment: if IE doesn't support the `target` property, then your code `e.target.id` is going to be a null reference error as soon as IE hits it.

Comment: I think `(e.target.id || e.srcElement.id)` will still throw an error in IE, as it will try to access the `id` property of the `target` property, but `target` does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

Internet Explorer doesn't pass the event object to the event handler - it sets it as a property of the window object instead. Also, it uses `srcElement` instead of `target`. Try

```
document.click = check;

function check(e)
{ 
    var target = e ? e.target : window.event.srcElement;
    var obj = document.getElementById('calendar_widget');

    if (obj != 'null')
    {
        if (target.id != 'show_calender')
                obj.style.display='none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, it's `document.onclick = ...`, not `document.click = ...`

Answer (score 2):

IE does not pass an event object as a parameter, the event object is accessed as a global identifier called `event`.  Also it doesn't use the term target, instead it uses `srcElement`.

Hence the equivalent code for IE is:-

```
 function check()
 { 

    var obj = document.getElementById('calendar_widget');

    if (obj != 'null')
    {
        if (event.srcElement.id != 'show_calender')
            obj.style.display='none';
    }
 }
```

Its for this reason that Javascript frameworks such as JQuery are so popular.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a classic event handling cross-browser problem. I'd advice using a library such as [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) or [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) for handling this in a much easier and straightforward manner. The problem is that IE does not pass the event object. Instead it can be found as a global object.