# Get element id in Internet Explorer using jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

```
var status = jQuery(event.target).parents("div").parents("div").next("div").attr('id');
alert("explorer this is for u :::" + status);
```

I'm getting the id in Chrome and all other browsers except Internet Explorer. I'm trying versions 9 and 10 of IE. Is there any other alternative for the `next` function?

Basically I want to get the parents's parent id of the clicked element.

[My fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/pUeue/863/)

It's working fine in Chrome but not in IE 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE doesn't support `event.target` so try with `this`

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function () {
    alert("test");
    var status = $(this).parent("div").attr('id'); 
    // also use parent since it's only one
    alert("explorer this is for u :::" + status);
});
```

[SO Link to event.target in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143236/2220391)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var status = jQuery(this).closest("div").attr('id');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cSPGN/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using event.currentTarget instead. It works on IE10 :

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function (event) {
    alert("test");
    var status = jQuery(event.currentTarget).parents("div").attr('id');
    alert("explorer this is for u :::" + status);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4x7nD/)