# Javascript: get element ID from event

Tags: javascript, events

How to get the ID of an element passed as (e)?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

    var tags = document.getElementsByClassName("tag");
    for (i=0; i<tags.length; i++){
    tags[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){ tagClick(e) }, false);
    }

}, false);

function tagClick(e){

    /* here I'm gonna need the event to cancel the bubble and the ID to work with it*/

    alert('The id of the element you clicked: ' + [?object].id);

    [?object].className='newClass';

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.cancelBubble = true;
}
```

I need to get the element/object inside tagClick so I can change its properties

html:

```
<div class="tag">
    <img src="/images/tags/sample.jpg"/>
    <label class="tagLabel">Sample</label>
</div>
```

See, the element with the event attached is the div, but ig gives me the image object instead when using e.srcElement.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using jQuery? All this headache can be written in one line of jQuery.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Because [jQuery is bloody slow](http://vanilla-js.com/)? In my project, I can write a delegated event handler in one line too because I created a *very specific* function to do the job. `addDelegatedEvent(document.body,function(t) {return r.nodeName == "TAG";},"click",function(e) {alert(e.target.id);});`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol what about browser compatibility? That's also major reason to use jQuery. Anyway let's not spam this question, there's chat for those things. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard `addDelegatedEvent` does the browser compatibility for me, because I programmed it to ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard When I'm done learning JavaScript then I'll use JQuery :)

Comment: @Azevedo I work with JavaScript for over 10 years and still not done learning it. So... ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you bind an event listener with `addEventListener`, it's called with `this` referring to the element you bound the event on. So `this.id` will be the `id` of the element (if it has one).

```
alert('The id of the element you clicked: ' + this.id);
```

But you're breaking that with this line:

```
tags[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){ tagClick(e) }, false);
```

...because you're putting an extra function in the middle, then calling `tagClick` without setting `this`. There's no need for that extra function, change that to:

```
tags[i].addEventListener('mousedown', tagClick, false);
```

...so `this` doesn't get messed up. Or alternately if you prefer to have the extra function, ensure `this` is maintained using `Function#call`:

```
tags[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){ tagClick.call(this, e) }, false);
```

...but there's no reason to do that with the `tagClick` function shown.

The (standard) event object also has the properties `target` (which may *not* be the element you bound the event on, it may well be a descendant) and `currentTarget` (which will be the element you bound the event on). But `this` is convenient and reliable if you use `addEventListener` (or even `attachEvent`, on IE).

Comment: @Azevedo: Oddly, I was just editing the answer because I noticed you did something odd in your `addEventListener`. See the update. :-) Sorry for missing that initially.

Comment: `tags[i].addEventListener('mousedown', tagClick, false);` seems to fit better. Works. Besides, it is already cancelling the bubble propagation [bacaused I cancelled the bubble propagation before it sticks?]

Comment: @Azevedo: I'm not following you, whether you put an extra function layer in doesn't relate to bubbling at all. Yes, you're cancelling bubbling, so once the event bubbles from the image to the element where you're hooking it, you're stopping it at that point.

Comment: The tags <div> are inside another <div> (background shader). Somehow, using `tags[i].addEventListener('mousedown', tagClick, false);` instead of `tags[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){ tagClick(e) }, false);` I don't need to cancel the Bubbling.

Comment: @Azevedo: That doesn't make any sense. I'd have to suggest observational error. :-)

Comment: In a second try, what is cancelling the buble is the msgbox I putted on it to 'debug'.

Comment: miss-clicked, sorry :)

Comment: @Azevedo: LOL :-) Have fun!

Comment: @Azevedo Since you already had accepted great answer, let me add live examples ;)
[With Direct binding](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/6kCmb/1/) and [With event delegation](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/wTa7W/1/)

Comment: Thanks! These fiddles sure help to understand the logic.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the target of the event with `e.target`.

However keep in mind that some browsers consider text nodes to be a target, so try something like this:

```
var t = e.target;
while(t && !t.id) t = t.parentNode;
if( t) {
    alert("You clicked element #"+t.id);
}
```

This will find the first element that actually has an ID.

Happy New Year!

EDIT: On second thought, if it's the "tag" element itself you want to refer to, just use `this`. In an event handler, `this` refers to the element that actually has the handler. Although in this case you'll need to change your handler to `('mousedown', tagClick, false)`

Or better still:

```
document.body.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e) {
    var t = e.target;
    while(t && t.nodeName != "TAG") { // note, must be uppercase
        t = t.parentNode;
    }
    if( t) {
        alert("You clicked on #"+t.id);
    }
},false);
```

Fewer event handlers is always better.

Comment: for IE it's [`srcElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534638(v=vs.85).aspx). (also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1143196/447356))

Comment: When you directly bind events, instead of `while(t && !t.id) t = t.parentNode;`, why not simply use `e.currentTarget`?

Comment: @ShadowWizard IE also uses `attachEvent`. Since OP is only using `addEventListener`, I'm only using `target`.

Comment: @niet: check the HTML. The problem is there is an image clicked inside a DIV (wich is what I want). Instead, it gives me the image.

Comment: Neat, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById("body").addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
 console.log(e.target.id);      
});
```

enjoy.