# Problem to recognize the selected HTML element in IE with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am generating a video through a function that takes as parameter an array of objects in json and the data-index of the HTML element.

With all this, the video is formed and works well. But, I am having problems in explorer / edge, that the data-index is not recognizing me and for this reason, it does not show the video.

```
$(document).on("click", ".openVideoCampana", function (ev) { getVideoCampana(jsonDestacados, ev); });

function getVideoCampana(jsonDataCampana, ev) {
    var dataIndex = ev.target.attributes[1].value;
    html = "<div class='closeVideo'>X</div>";
    if (jsonDataCampana[0].data[dataIndex].videoType == "true") {
        html += "<iframe type=\"text/html\" width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"" + jsonDataCampana[0].data[dataIndex].video + "\" frameborder=\"0\"/>";
    } else {
        html += "<video class=\"videoNuevo videoRedPaz\" autoplay controls>";
        html += "<source src=\"" + jsonDataCampana[0].data[dataIndex].video + "\">";
        html += "</video>";
    }
    $(".fnJSON_video").html(html);
    $(".fnJSON_video").fadeIn("fast");
}
```

The happens with the var `dataIndex = ev.target.attributes[1].value;`

Internet explorer does not recognize the ev.target.attributes[1].value...

Is there an alternative for this? This works well for me in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera

Comment: try `(ev.target || ev.srcElement).attributes`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE e.target.id is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143196/ie-e-target-id-is-not-working)