# IE $(e.target.closest(".k-event")).data("uid") Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Using Telerik (Kendo UI) Scheduler and the delete event function I have does not work in IE (even IE11) but does work in Edge, Chrome and FireFox.

The JS Console give the following error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'closest'
```

My code is:

```
var eventUID = $(e.target.closest(".k-event")).data("uid");
```

What alternative can I user for IE or better still what could I use that will work with all the above browsers including IE (at least IE11). This could be jQuery or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like e.target isn't a jquery Object. 
Try: $($(e.target).closest(".k-event")).data("uid");

Comment: .closest is jQuery ( https://api.jquery.com/closest/ ) e.target is javascript but some research has given me this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143196/ie-e-target-id-is-not-working …. I will try your suggestion and report. Thanks